# Xcode15 - Library Search Paths broken after upgrade

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, c++20, xcode15

I use Xcode to develop C++ software, and every time I upgrade Xcode after a major release, the update breaks my Library Search Paths to specified libraries to link that I am using in my project.  When I try to run the program after the upgrade, the run fails as it tries to link the libraries in paths I do not specify, while neglecting the paths that I actually specify.

This happened last year, and I had to recreate the entire project with my files just to get Xcode to behave properly.  A year later, I'm looking at the same problem with upgrading to Xcode 15.

```
My project uses the following libraries:
    libmysqlcppconn.9.dylib
    libcurl.4.dylib
    libcrypto.1.1.dylib
    libssl.1.1.dylib

Which are in the following paths: 
    /usr/local/mysql-connector-c++-8.0.32/lib64/
    /usr/local/Cellar/curl/8.0.1/lib/
    /usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1d/lib/
```

Even examining my .plist file, the paths are present:
(Including the entire debug config so you can see the compiler options incase I'm missing something)

```
    /* Begin XCBuildConfiguration section */
        433351C729DBA97D005D693C /* Debug */ = {
            isa = XCBuildConfiguration;
            buildSettings = {
                ALWAYS_SEARCH_USER_PATHS = NO;
                CLANG_ANALYZER_NONNULL = YES;
                CLANG_ANALYZER_NUMBER_OBJECT_CONVERSION = YES_AGGRESSIVE;
                CLANG_CXX_LANGUAGE_STANDARD = "c++20";
                CLANG_ENABLE_MODULES = YES;
                CLANG_ENABLE_OBJC_ARC = YES;
                CLANG_ENABLE_OBJC_WEAK = YES;
                CLANG_WARN_BLOCK_CAPTURE_AUTORELEASING = YES;
                CLANG_WARN_BOOL_CONVERSION = YES;
                CLANG_WARN_COMMA = YES;
                CLANG_WARN_CONSTANT_CONVERSION = YES;
                CLANG_WARN_DEPRECATED_OBJC_IMPLEMENTATIONS = YES;
                CLANG_WARN_DIRECT_OBJC_ISA_USAGE = YES_ERROR;
                CLANG_WARN_DOCUMENTATION_COMMENTS = YES;
                CLANG_WARN_EMPTY_BODY = YES;
                CLANG_WARN_ENUM_CONVERSION = YES;
                CLANG_WARN_INFINITE_RECURSION = YES;
                CLANG_WARN_INT_CONVERSION = YES;
                CLANG_WARN_NON_LITERAL_NULL_CONVERSION = YES;
                CLANG_WARN_OBJC_IMPLICIT_RETAIN_SELF = YES;
                CLANG_WARN_OBJC_LITERAL_CONVERSION = YES;
                CLANG_WARN_OBJC_ROOT_CLASS = YES_ERROR;
                CLANG_WARN_QUOTED_INCLUDE_IN_FRAMEWORK_HEADER = YES;
                CLANG_WARN_RANGE_LOOP_ANALYSIS = YES;
                CLANG_WARN_STRICT_PROTOTYPES = YES;
                CLANG_WARN_SUSPICIOUS_MOVE = YES;
                CLANG_WARN_UNGUARDED_AVAILABILITY = YES_AGGRESSIVE;
                CLANG_WARN_UNREACHABLE_CODE = YES;
                CLANG_WARN__DUPLICATE_METHOD_MATCH = YES;
                CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY = "Mac Developer";
                COPY_PHASE_STRIP = NO;
                DEBUG_INFORMATION_FORMAT = dwarf;
                ENABLE_STRICT_OBJC_MSGSEND = YES;
                ENABLE_TESTABILITY = YES;
                GCC_C_LANGUAGE_STANDARD = gnu11;
                GCC_DYNAMIC_NO_PIC = NO;
                GCC_NO_COMMON_BLOCKS = YES;
                GCC_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL = 0;
                GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS = (
                    "DEBUG=1",
                    "$(inherited)",
                );
                GCC_WARN_64_TO_32_BIT_CONVERSION = YES;
                GCC_WARN_ABOUT_RETURN_TYPE = YES_ERROR;
                GCC_WARN_UNDECLARED_SELECTOR = YES;
                GCC_WARN_UNINITIALIZED_AUTOS = YES_AGGRESSIVE;
                GCC_WARN_UNUSED_FUNCTION = YES;
                GCC_WARN_UNUSED_VARIABLE = YES;
                LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS = (
                    "/usr/local/mysql-connector-c++-8.0.32/lib64/",
                    "/usr/local/Cellar/curl/8.0.1/lib/",
                    "/usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1d/lib/",
                    "/usr/local/Cellar/curl/8.0.1/lib/"
                );
                "LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS[arch=*]" = "";
                MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 13.0;
                MTL_ENABLE_DEBUG_INFO = INCLUDE_SOURCE;
                MTL_FAST_MATH = YES;
                ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH = YES;
                SDKROOT = macosx;
            };
            name = Debug;
        };
```

When I run the program, here is the crash report:

```
    dyld[23554]: Library not loaded: libcrypto.1.1.dylib
  Referenced from: <857C24D7-4369-3475-9EF1-E9EBD423B3DB> /Users/USR/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Hub-fpmiypgiftiippagwwmypglahtxj/Build/Products/Debug/Hub

    Reason: tried: '/Users/USR/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Hub-fpmiypgiftiippagwwmypglahtxj/Build/Products/Debug/libcrypto.1.1.dylib' (no such file),
    '/usr/lib/system/introspection/libcrypto.1.1.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache),
    'libcrypto.1.1.dylib' (no such file), 
    '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OSlibcrypto.1.1.dylib' (no such file), 
    'libcrypto.1.1.dylib' (no such file), 
    '/Users/USR/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Hub-fpmiypgiftiippagwwmypglahtxj/Build/Products/Debug/libcrypto.1.1.dylib' (no such file),
    '/usr/lib/system/introspection/libcrypto.1.1.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache),
    '/Users/USR/Documents/workspace/Hub Working Directory/libcrypto.1.1.dylib' (no such file),
    '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Users/USR/Documents/workspace/Hub Working Directory/libcrypto.1.1.dylib' (no such file), 
    '/Users/USR/Documents/workspace/Hub Working Directory/libcrypto.1.1.dylib' (no such file)
```

(edited the text above for readability, highlighting the search paths)

It appears that it's not even attempting to search the paths that were specified.  Last time this happened, not only did I have to recreate the entire .xcodeproj file, but also create symlinks in specific directories pointing to the correct library locations as a work around.  After the update again, I find myself in the same position.

Is there a setting or default location somewhere that is overriding my Library Search Paths?
Is there a way to fix this issue without recreating the file?
Has anyone else had this issue too?

I appreciate any help or input anyone has on this.